# auto fill html form using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a HTML form which has 3 text input fields: `id`, `name`, and `contact`. My DB table has same named columns and the values are `id=1`, `name=mark` & `contact=1234`. Now, if I enter '1' in my html form's id field & press enter then how can the rest of the form's field (like: `name`, `contact`) will be automatically filled?

What I've done so far is:

my **index.html** file(I think its wrong because I didn't use JSON before):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type = javascript>

$("#email").bind("change", function(e){
  $.getJSON("lookup.php?email=" + $("#email").val(),
        function(data){
          $.each(data, function(i,item){
            if (item.field == "first_name") {
              $("#first_name").val(item.value);
            } else if (item.field == "last_name") {
              $("#last_name").val(item.value);
            }
          });
        });
});


</script>>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<input  type="text" name="email" id="email" />
<input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" />
<input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

my **lookup.php** file:

```
<?php
//look up the record based on email and get the firstname and lastname
$email=$_GET['$email'];

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("json", $con); //DB name= json

 mysql_select_db("json"); //DB name= json

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM json1 
     WHERE email LIKE '$email%'");      //DB table name=json1
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
//build the JSON array for return
$json = array(array('field' => 'first_name', 
                    'value' => $firstName), 
              array('field' => 'last_name', 
                    'value' => $last_name));
echo json_encode($json );
        }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fill the form without reloading the page you will have to use Ajax to request the data from the server (database) and then fill it using javascript, i suggest reading about ajax functions with jquery.

if you want for example to fill the id and click a button and the page will reload with the data, use the php post method, a quick example:

```
<?php
    if($_POST['getdata']){
        $id = $_POST['itemID'];
        /*
        connect to the database and get the data here and return in with an array called $data for example
        */
    }
    if($_POST['savedata']){
        /*
        use this if you want to do another action to the form, update the values for example
        */
    }
?>
<form action='' method='POST'>
    <input name="id" value="<?php echo $data['id'];?>" type="text" />
    <input name="name" value="<?php echo $data['name'];?>" type="text" />
    <input name="contact" value="<?php echo $data['contact'];?>" type="text" />
    <input name="getdata" value="Get Data" type="submit" />
    <input name="savedata" value="Save Data" type="submit" />
</form>
```

UPDATE:

regarding your update

first of all you better use PDO or MySQLi database instead of MySQL function because mysql_* is no longer maintained so since you are fresh to php learn PDO instead.

to your code, if you are expecting a single row from the database select statement, you should not use `while()` because its used to loop through the mysql object which has more than one row.

if we assume your table has exactly `email, firstname, lastname` fetch it directly into an array:

```
$myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

then convert that array into json and print it out

```
echo json_encode($myrow);
exit();
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply :) but, actually i wanted to retrieve back the data without using any submit button. if i use ajax, what approach i need to use? do you have any relevant example please?

Comment: read this [dynamically fill in form values with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/558445/dynamically-fill-in-form-values-with-jquery)

Comment: thanks for the link.. looks like its used JSON. i tried the code but it didn't work for me.. maybe i did some wrong :(

Comment: since you (tried) dont be ashamed to paste your code here again, you will get guided until it works

Comment: Ok :) shall i edit the post to put the code? because the comment area is too short to put the code..

Comment: I am not aware of the community posting rules, but I think you should edit the post, consider adding a comment saying its update, and post your code

Comment: post edited.. lots of correction need to be made, i guess :/

Comment: @Atiqur i have updated my answer as well

Comment: this thing seems complex to me :( do you have any other suggestions for this post? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13327773/auto-fill-text-field-after-pressing-enter-key)

Comment: @Atiqur i have already answered you there, and by the way if you found my help useful mark it as accept answer using the check mark under the vote :)

Comment: @Atiqur the other one please ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try using some php MVC framework, like Codeigniter, cakephp, yii.

Comment: thanks for reply but i'm newbie at this area so no idea about Codeigniter, cakephp, yii :(

Comment: Well, you have to spend some time to learn. Good luck. I voted up to your question.