# auto fill text field after pressing enter key

Tags: php, ajax

i got an useful tutorial where if you input 'id' [or first 1-2 letter of your id], the rest of form's field will filled automatically by pulling data from mysql database. this thing will happen without pressing ENTER key! now, what i'm trying to do is, i'll input the full 'id' & press ENTER key to fill the rest of form's field! what modification would need for this code below? here is my index.html file:

```
<html> 
    <body> 
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        function ajaxFunction(){ 
    var http;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible! 

    try{ 
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari 
        http = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    } catch (e){ 
        // Internet Explorer Browsers 
        try{ 
            http = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); 
        } catch (e) { 
            try{ 
                http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
            } catch (e){ 
                // Something went wrong 
                alert("Your browser broke!"); 
                return false; 
            } 
        }
    }

    var url = "getagentids.php?param=";
                var idValue = document.getElementById("agid").value;
                var myRandom = parseInt(Math.random()*99999999);  // cache buster
                http.open("GET", "getagentids.php?param=" + escape(idValue) + "&rand=" + myRandom, true);
                http.onreadystatechange = handleHttpResponse;
                http.send(null);
         function handleHttpResponse() {
                    if (http.readyState == 4) {
                        results = http.responseText.split(",");
                        document.getElementById('agfn').value = results[0];
                        document.getElementById('agsal').value = results[1];
                        document.getElementById('agtel').value = results[2];
                        document.getElementById('agid').value = results[3];
                    }
                } 
    }
</script> 

        <form name="schform">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Contact ID:</td>
                    <td><input id="agid" type="text"
                               name="contactid" onKeyUp="ajaxFunction()"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tel Number:</td>
                    <td><input id="agtel" type="text"
                               name="contacttel"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name:</td>
                    <td><input id="agfn" type="text"
                               name="contactfullname"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Salutation:</td>
                    <td><input id="agsal" type="text"
                               name="contactsalutation"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="reset" value="Clear"></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>

    </body> 
</html>
```

and here is my getagentids.php file:

```
<?php

error_reporting(0); // turns off error reporting

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("contactdetail", $con);

 mysql_select_db("contactdetail");

 $param=$_GET['param']; 

if (strlen($param) > 0) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contact 
     WHERE contactid LIKE '$param%'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $agentname = $myrow["contactfullname"];
            $agenttel = $myrow["contacttel"];
            $agentsal = $myrow["contactsalutation"];
            $agentid = $myrow["contactid"];
            $textout .= $agentid . ", " . $agentname . ", " . $agenttel . ", " . $agentsal;
        }
    } else {
        $textout = " , , ," . $param;
    }
}
echo $textout;
?>
```

Comment: Is this function working without enter, if so then you should just check whether enter has been pressed or not.

Comment: currently its working without pressing enter! but i want to fill the form's field by input id & then pressing enter key!

Comment: Do you want to fill the inputs after pressing the enter key and before you call/send ajax request ?

Comment: yeah, i want to input the ID only & then press enter to get filled the other fields from database..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your `ajaxFunction` like (just paste the code at the top of your `ajaxFunction`)

```
function ajaxFunction(e){
    var e=e || window.event;
    var keycode=e.which || e.keyCode;
    if(keycode!==13 || (e.target||e.srcElement).value=='') return false;
   // rest of your code
}​
```

And change your `onKeyUp` with this (notice `event` in the argument)

```
<input id="agid" type="text" name="contactid" onKeyUp="ajaxFunction(event)">​
```

[**Just for an idea**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/xnVpe/2/).

Comment: thanks for reply bro, but its doing the same thing as before. [retrieve  data without pressing ENTER key]

Comment: @Atiqur, Check the check the example, it's working, the alert will work only after you press enter. Make sure you have did it in right way.

Comment: well bro, is it like: function ajaxFunction(e){
    var e=e || window.event;
    var keycode=e.which || e.keyCode;
    if(keycode!==13 || (e.target||e.srcElement).value==''){ 
    var http;
     
    try{ 
      
        http = new XMLHttpRequest(); ..........
............document.getElementById('agtel').value = results[2];
                        document.getElementById('agid').value = results[3];
                    }
                } 
 }
}

Comment: and the form: <input id="agid" type="text"
                               name="contactid" onkeyup="ajaxFunction(event)">

Comment: bro its done! :D i just remove the '!' from "if(keycode!==13" & its working... thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 2):

first create a javascript function to detect if the Enter key is pressed and call the `ajaxFunction` from within it:

```
function run(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
       ajaxFunction();
       return false; //disable the default Enter behavior 
    }
    return true;
}
```

change the `onKeyUp="ajaxFunction()"` call in the Contact ID text input into `onKeyUp="run()"`

Comment: thanks for comment :) shall i put ajaxFunction() inside of run()? well, i put it already but no luck :(

Comment: @Atiqur yes, use the whole javascript function i provided and only change the onKeyUp to run() instead of ajaxFunction

Comment: no luck yet :( i did like---> 'code'function run(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
       function ajaxFunction(){ 
    var http;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible! 
     
    try{ 
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari 
        http = new XMLHttpRequest();
........
........
return false; //disable the default Enter behavior 
    }
    return true;

 }

Comment: @Atiqur dude, just paste the function block ABOVE your ajaxFunction()

Comment: i tried, but not working!:( is the form's field is ok? code: tr>
                    <td>Contact ID:</td>
                    <td><input id="agid" type="text"
                               name="contactid" onkeyup="run()"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

Comment: are you trying it on your machine or online? if its online lets have a look

Comment: bro, its done :) check out my comment under @Sheikh's answer. thanks for helping :)

Comment: congratulation, you better now start learning programming basics, before jumping into some advanced topics, cause still the code you are using is not fully secure