# Can i use an ajax button to take a drop down value and fill a form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

i have been trying to work out using Jquery and a drop down box to fill input forms with no success and i am trying to find a way around this till i can eventually figure it out. What i would like to know if it is possible to populate a drop down list with sql then once selected take that value and run a sql command to get the rest of the line of data and $_GET into input fields.

i have been reviewing samples and but most samples output table data and can't find anything that will pull to a input field so i can process the form into a database.

I am just looking for an idea or direction to where i should be looking for such a task, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically fill in form values with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/558445/dynamically-fill-in-form-values-with-jquery)

Comment: You have to provide code examples so we can see what you've already tried @Glenn Zealous

Comment: Which PHP Framework you are using for this purpose? or using just a .php file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, by using [JQuery Library](https://jquery.com/) and writing your own PHP functionality you can easily do that.

You need and a HTML Select box:

```
<select id="myselectbox">
    <option>Select</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="myinputbox">
```

A JQuery Ajax request for getting your data for the Select Box, which will be triggered when your Web Document will get ready and a Onchange event for the Select Box with an-other Ajax request with POST type:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $.get( "myfunctions/get_records_for_select.php", function( data ) {
    //Look we will change the HTML content for our select-box on success
    $( "#myselectbox" ).html( data );
  });

  $( "#myselectbox" ).change(function() {

    $.post( "myfunctions/get_records_by_id.php", { selectedId: $(this).val() })
    .done(function( data ) {
      $( "#myinputbox" ).val( data );
    });

 });
});
</script>
```

Your .PHP file to that will receive the AJAX request:

```
// your get_records_for_select.php file

$yourSql = "select ...";
$results = run_sql($yourSql);
$html = "<option>Select</option>";
foreach($results as $record){
    $html .= "<option value='".$record['id']."'>".$record['title']."</option>";
}

echo $html;exit;
```

Your second .PHP file to that will receive the POST TYPE AJAX request:

```
// your get_records_by_id.php file
$post_data $_POST['selectedId'];
$yourSql = "select ... WHERE id=".$post_data;
$results = run_sql($yourSql);
$row = $results->row();
echo $row['yourvalue'];exit;
```

**I hope now you can get some idea :)**

Comment: This is almost close to perfect and it is really much appreciated, i can see how how such a function could be executed now. but i do have a question as i can see the function working but the sql is not populated the drop down list while instead is echo'ing a line of the file. Then when that open is selected it is echo'ing the POST code to the inbox.

the core of it is working but i still need to tweak it more before adding to the script.

Comment: @GlennZealous glad to know that it helped you :) and the question you have just asked me, I am not able to get it. I think you should post an other Question with your current code. So, I or someone other will be able to fix your issue and help you :)

Comment: I have done that and it is kinda 1 step forward 2 steps back. i can see that this code does work but i just need to slap it a few times in the face with a chair and a octopus wrapped around that chair

Comment: great, happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

TEST.php

```
       <? 


       if(isset($_GET['name'])) {
       /*Some queries if need*/
       echo '{"name":"yiu send name ['.$_GET['name'].'] and may be some other data'.'"}';
       }
        else {

       $bd_host='localhost';
       $bd_user='root';
       $bd_password='';
       $bd_base='db_name';

       /*connect to db*/
       $con=mysql_connect($bd_host, $bd_user, $bd_password); 

       /*control connection*/
       if(!con) {
       echo 'Error.'; 
       exit; 
       }

       /*select databese name*/
       mysql_select_db($bd_base, $con); 

       /*set encode to utf-8*/
       mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');



       $sql="Select name from users limit 10"
       $res=mysql_query($sql);
       ?>
       <head>
       <style>
       div{background-color:red;width:150px;color:white;}
       ul{display:none;position:absolute;width:150px;margin:0;padding:0;background-color:yellow;color:black;}
       div:hover ul{display:block;}
       .filled{background-color:blue;}
       </style>
       </head>
       <div>button<ul>
       <?
       While($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) { ?>
       <li onclick="ajax('<? echo $row['name']; ?>');return false;"><? echo $row['name']; ?></li>
       <?
       }
       ?>
       </ul></div>
       <input type="text" value="none" id="id1">
       <?
       }
       ?>

       <script>           
       function ajax(name) {
       var url='/test.php?name='+name;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                   xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
               } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                   xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
               }
                   xmlhttp.open('GET', url, true);

               xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                   if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                       myfunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
                   }
               }

                   xmlhttp.send(null );


               function myfunction(response) {
       var= arr; 
       arr = JSON.parse(response);
       document.getElementById('id1').value=arr.name;
       document.getElementById('id1').className='filled';
       alert ('The input was filled with '+arr.name);
       }

       }
       </script>    

      /*END of test.php*/
```